# Consider a sequence of polynomials with real coefficients defined by

Tags: polynomials

Consider a sequence of polynomials with real coefficients defined by:

$$p_0=(x^2 +1)(x^2 +2).....(x^2 +1009)$$

with subsequent polynomials defined by $$p_{k+1} (x)  :=p_k (x+1) - p_k (x) $$ for $x>0$.
Find the
least n such that

$$p_n (1)=p_n (2)=......=p_n (5000).$$

My attempt :

Degree of the first given polynomial is 2018. And it can be seen that for $p_n (x) =2018-n$. So to have 5000 roots it must be constant function. So n=2018.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I was typing my answer/hint while your edit came. IMHO yours is the way to do this.

Comment: I am learning the use of latex. So I am slow in writing these. But thanks for clearing my doubt. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the following:

- $p_0(x)$ has degree $2018$.
- $\deg p_{k+1}=\deg p_k-1$ for all $k$.
- For $p_n(x)-p_n(1)$ to have $5000$ zeros it must have either degree $\ge5000$ or be the constant zero.

Comment: Thanks sir. Its same what I added after editing I suppose.

Comment: Sir, the degree of the zero polynomial is $-\infty$ so isn't the question incorrect?

Comment: @Tapi When $p_n(x)$ is of degree zero we have $p_n(x)=p_n(1)$ for all integers $x$.